# Attempt to invoke virtual method '...' on a null object reference at com.comp.Project

Tags: java, android, error-handling, runtime-error

I am getting a error while debugging and I don't know why.

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void layout.CardFragment.setCard(com.mycomp.MyCards.Card)' on a null object reference at com.mycomp.MyCards.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
```

I think this is saying that the `Card` object that I am trying to pass into `cardFragment.setCard(Card card)` is null. I have checked it and it's not null.

MainActivity.java

```
 1 package com.mycomp.MyCards;
 2 
 3 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 4 import android.os.Bundle;
 5 
 6 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 7     public Card cardApples;
 8 public CardFragment cardFragment = (CardFragment) 
 9             getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgCard);
10 
11     @Override
12     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
13         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
14         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
15         createDummyCards();
16 --->    cardFragment.setCard(cardApples);
17     }
18 
19     public void createDummyCards() {
20         cardApples = new Card(new SideText("Apple"), new SideText("Red"));
21     }
22 }
```

Card.java

```
package com.mycomp.MyCards;

public class Card {
    public Side[] sides;

    public Card(Side...sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }    
}
```

Side.java

```
package com.mycomp.MyCards;

public class Side {}
```

SideText.java

```
package com.mycomp.MyCards;

public class SideText extends Side{
    public String text;

    public SideText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

CardFragment.java

```
package com.midassoft.testingerror;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CardFragment extends Fragment {
    private Card card;
    private int sideIndex;

    private static TextView lblText;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false);
        lblText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblText);
        return view;
    }

    public void setCard(Card card) {
        this.card = card;
        sideIndex = 0;
        showSide();
    }

    private void showSide() {
        Side side = card.sides[sideIndex];
        switch (side.getClass().getName()) {
            case "SideText":
                lblText.setText(((SideText) side).text);
                break;
            case "SideMultipleChoice":
                ///do stuff
                break;
            case "SideTrueFalse":
                ///do stuff
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You tried to get fragment object before attaching the view, that's why it didn't find the view `id` and give you a null object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one:

```
public CardFragment cardFragment;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     createDummyCards();
     cardFragment = (CardFragment) 
         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgCard);
     cardFragment.setCard(cardApples);
 }
```

Comment: That worked. Why did that work? Why did me trying to initialize it on top return a null?

Comment: Yes, because you called `findViewById()` before attaching your view (e.g. `setContentView()`).

Comment: Oh. That makes since. Thank you.